# codeigniter page redirection issue

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am new to codeigniter frame work and i am trying to design a member registration form using that framework. I have used the following code to insert the member.

```
<?php
    Class data extends CI_Model
    {

    function add_form()
     {
        $this->load->database();

        $val = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
        'age' => $this->input->post('age'),
        'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
        'phoneno' => $this->input->post('phone'),
         );
        $insert=$this->db->insert('tbl_member',$val);

     }
    }
?>
```

If the member details inserted into the database successfully i have to redirect it to the view member details page with success message. In that page i have to display the member details fetched from the database. I don't know how to redirect and check whether the insert is true. How can i do that?

Comment: this is really bad form calling `$this->input->post('#')` inside your model.  Please validate in **CONTROLLER**, then pass sanitized values to your model. A good method is a clean `array()` of values to insert.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the insert was successful with:

```
$this->db->affected_rows()
```

to return the number of records inserted. You can then redirect the user to the appropriate page using the URL helper's redirect function:

```
redirect('path/to/redirect/to');
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will work for you

```
<?php
    Class data extends CI_Model
    {

    function add_form()
     {
        $this->load->database();

        $val = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
        'age' => $this->input->post('age'),
        'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
        'phoneno' => $this->input->post('phone'),
         );
        if( $this->db->insert('tbl_member',$val) ) {
            $insert= $this->db->insert_id();
            return $this->insert_success($insert);
        } else {
           return false;
        }

     }
    }
?>
```

And your insert_success method would be:

```
function insert_success($userId)
  {
    $data = $this->db->query('query-to-fetch-details-with-user-id');
    return $data->result_array();
  }
```